# Passing context in django auth views

Tags: django

I have this in my django project:

```
path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html'), 
    name='password_change_done'),

path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html'), 
    name='password_change'),
```

in these html pages for the above urls I have to pass some information too as context. So how do I pass context in such type of urls which have no custom view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `extra_context` argument of the `as_view` function as defined in [the documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView).

Example :

```
path(
    'password_change/', 
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='password_change.html',
        extra_context={'foo': 'bar'}
    ), 
    name='password_change'
),
```

Then you can use `{{ foo }}` in your template.